# Is there a way to output bash command results in a different format from default when using Python CGI

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, python-2.7, cgi

When running bash commands from Python to a webpage, succesful output to the webpage occurs when no output options are set. However, i'd like to save the output to an xml file and display the output to the webpage. I get an error when attempting to do this:

[image]

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import os
# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import time

# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
# Get data from fields
niktoValue = form.getvalue('niktoInput')


# Get data from fields
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Nikto Scan Information for %s </h2>" % (niktoValue)


def bash(command):
    return subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', command])

def niktoScan():
    res = bash("nikto -h %s -output xml" % niktoValue).splitlines()
    print(res)



niktoScan()

print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Error 13 is normally *"Permission denied"*.

I suspect your CGI script is running as the `_www` user rather than as your regular user when you are logged in at your desktop. You can test by running `id` in the `bash` script under the http server or looking in your http server config file - maybe `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` for the part that looks like this:

> User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
> It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
> running httpd, as with most system services.
>
> User _www
> Group _www

I am unfamiliar with the `nikto` program, so you will need to find out from its author how to allow the `www` user to run it - maybe by adding that user to a Unix group, maybe via `sudo`, maybe something else.